# I tried using the <map> tag to make a round picture working like a link but it doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, imagemap

So I wanna make let's say a round button but I tried every answer to a similar question on this page and it doesn't work, I guess there's a mistake in my code. Could someone check it?bThe problem is that the area around the image is clickable too, I used border-radius. (I am new to this whole programming stuff.)

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="hotel">
    <img src="http://www.litorehotel.com/web/en/images/placeholders/1920x1200-0.jpg" height="400" width="400" alt="Our hotels and resorts" usemap="#hotel">
    <p class="hotimg">Our hotels and resorts</p>
  </div>
</a>

<map name="hotel">
  <area shape="circle" coords="961, 603, 819" href="#" />
</map>
```

Comment: Why don't you just style the a-tag to be a round button, instead of making a map?

Comment: It's also not proper to place a block element `div` within an inline element `a`. Could you show us what it's supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you press tab, you can see the outline of your shape. It's simply too big and positioned off to the side.

However, I also agree with the suggestion of using `css` as opposed to a `map`.

[image]